# Bearing angle and distance between heading and target point

Tags: trigonometry

I'd like to calculate the bearing angle and the distance between heading point and target point with three coordinates for an arduino navigation.

Coordinate system looks something like this.

[image]

$(x_1, y_1)$ = heading point, $(x_3, y_3)$ = target point

Angle range should be $-180^\circ$ to $+180^\circ$ so it is possible to continuously adjust bearing angle to zero to drive towards way-point.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three points form a triangle, as in the figure below:

[image]

You know the coordinates of the three vertices: $H(x_H,y_H)$, $A(x_A,y_A)$, and $T(x_T,y_T)$. The goal is to compute the angle between $\vec{AT}$ and $\vec{AH}$. I write these as vectors because you want an *oriented* angle, starting from the segment $\vec{AT}$ and increasing counterclockwise towards $\vec{AH}$.

The derivation below will result in an angle in the range $0 \le \theta < 360^\circ$. You can adjust the range to $-180^\circ \le \theta < 180^\circ$ by simply subtracting $180^\circ$ from the value we'll compute below.

We'll obtain the angle by making use of the **dot** and **cross** products of the vectors $\vec{AT}$ and $\vec{AH}$ to find the values of $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$, respectively. The [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) between two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a number which can be computed in two ways:
$$
\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b} \equiv a_x\,b_x + a_y\,b_y = |\,\vec{a}\,|\,|\,\vec{b}\,|\cos\theta
$$

Similarly, the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) between two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is also a number which can be computed in two ways:
$$
\vec{a}\times\vec{b} \equiv a_x\,b_y - a_y\,b_x = |\,\vec{a}\,|\,|\,\vec{b}\,|\sin\theta
$$

Dividing the result from the cross product by the result for the dot product, we can compute $\tan\theta$:
$$
\tan\theta \equiv \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta} = \frac{a_x\,b_y - a_y\,b_x}{a_x\,b_x + a_y\,b_y}
$$
Note that we can't perform that division when $\cos\theta$ (the denominator) is zero, that is, when $\theta = 90^\circ$ or when $\theta = 270^\circ$. Now for the actual computation.

> Let
>   $$
> (\, a_x \,,\, a_y \,) = \left(\,x_T-x_A \,,\, y_T-y_A \,\right)
> $$
>   $$
> (\, b_x \,,\, b_y \,) = \left(\,x_H-x_A \,,\, y_H-y_A \,\right)
> $$
>   $$
> s = a_x\,b_y - a_y\,b_x
> $$
>   $$
> c = a_x\,b_x + a_y\,b_y
> $$
>   Then,
>   $$
> \theta = 0^\circ
> \quad\mbox{if}\quad
> s = 0
> \quad\mbox{and}\quad
> c > 0
> $$
>   $$
> \theta = 90^\circ
> \quad\mbox{if}\quad
> s > 0
> \quad\mbox{and}\quad
> c = 0
> $$
>   $$
> \theta = 180^\circ
> \quad\mbox{if}\quad
> s = 0
> \quad\mbox{and}\quad
> c < 0
> $$
>   $$
> \theta = 270^\circ
> \quad\mbox{if}\quad
> s < 0
> \quad\mbox{and}\quad
> c = 0
> $$
>   Now let
>   $$
> \theta_0 = \arctan\left|\frac{s}{c}\right|
> \quad\mbox{if}\quad
> c \ne 0
> $$
>   Then,
>   $$
> \theta = \theta_0
> \quad\mbox{if} \quad s > 0
> \quad\mbox{and}\quad c > 0
> $$
>   $$
> \theta = 180^\circ - \theta_0
> \quad\mbox{if} \quad s > 0
> \quad\mbox{and}\quad c < 0
> $$
>   $$
> \theta = 180^\circ + \theta_0
> \quad\mbox{if} \quad s < 0
> \quad\mbox{and}\quad c < 0
> $$
>   $$
> \theta = 360^\circ - \theta_0
> \quad\mbox{if} \quad s < 0
> \quad\mbox{and}\quad c > 0
> $$

The case when both $c = 0$ and $s = 0$ cannot happen unless the three points $A$, $T$, and $H$ coincide. As I said at the top, this results in $0 \le \theta < 360^\circ$ but you can adjust the range to $-180^\circ \le \theta < 180^\circ$ by subtracting $180^\circ$ from the angle computed above.

Comment: correct, but assume above image flipped to downwards such a way that point H goes down, in that case I want negative angle value, bus cos(-x) = cos(+x) ?

Comment: Simple: Keep track of whether $H$ is to one side or the other of the segment $\overline{AT}$. You can do that efficiently by computing the cross product: $\vec{AT} \times \vec{AH}$. In two dimensions, the cross product is simply a real number and, in this case, computed as I suggest, gives a **positive** value when $H$ is to the **left** of the segment $\overline{AT}$ (i.e., **above**), a **zero** value when it's crossing to the other side, and a **negative** value when $H$ is to the **right** of the segment $\overline{AT}$ (i.e., **below**).

Comment: Note that $\vec{AT} = T - A = (x_3-x_2, y_3-y_2)$ and $\vec{AH} = H - A = (x_1-x_2, y_1-y_2)$, and the cross product between two vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ is simply $\vec{a} \times \vec{b} = a_x\,b_y - a_y\,b_x$.

Comment: In fact, you could use the cross-product to compute the angle instead of the law of cosines. I'll edit my answer to explain how.

Comment: There is one problem, resultant angle will be always in the range of either 0 to +90 or 0 to -90.

For first and fourth quadrant it is 0 to +90 and second and third quadrant it is 0 to -90

How can I express them in the range of -180 to +180?

That is for total second and third quandrant 0 to -180 and for total first and fourth quadrant it should be 0 to +180 so I can adjust the turnings.

Comment: @ronroo I've rewritten my entire answer to make it simpler, more direct, and hopefully more understandable. It also addresses the issue you raised with the range. Please let me know if you still have questions about it.